# Java Media Framework & Windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows-8.1, jmf

I create soft based on the JMF. Soft consists of the server transmitted video using RTSP and clients which can play video. 
I tested it in the Windows XP and it worked very well. But  I had a problem with Windows 8. 
I would say a very strange problem! I installed JMStudio and tested and saw the same one. 
Description of the problem: VisualComponent of JMF MediaPlayer doesn't show RTSP video when it is fully inside of the screen. It works well if partly VisualComponent is outside of the screen! JMStudio plays video very well if I "Open File...". The problem only occurs when working through RTSP by "Open URL..." and, for example run "rtsp://192.168.56.1:554/VIDEO.AVI" 
I used Windows 8.1, JMF 2.1.1e, jdk-7u51-windows-i586, K-Lite_Codec_Pack version 4.3.1 or Xvid-1.3.3. In all cases audio works well.

I tried 64-bit version of JDK, newer codecs such as K-Lite 1080 but JMStudio didn't work at all.

I was able to run my program in full-screen mode increasing window outside of the screen to 10 pixels: setBounds (-10, -10, dimScreen.width+20, dimScreen.height+20) and full-screen shows well. 
I don't know how to solve the problem for a small window.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work on 64 machines. So you need to install 32bit JDK verion as well. You might want to uninstall 64bit if you want.